# Removing word suffixes to reduce inflected

Tags: java, algorithm

Question:
Stemming removes word suffixes to reduce inflected (or sometimes derived) words to their base or root form.
E.g. “friendly” is an inflection of “friend”. By stemming (in this case stemming means removing the suffix “ly”), “friendly” is reduced to “friend”.
Given a list of tokens and a list of suffixes
Your task is to
write a function that prints to the standard output (stdout) all the tokens having their suffix removed if found in the list of suffixes (please print one token per line)
for each token if there is more than one suffix that can be removed please choose the one that is the longest
Note that your function will receive the following arguments:
tokens
which is an array of strings giving the tokens described above
suffixes
which is an array of strings giving the suffixes described above
Data constraints
the length of the tokens array will not exceed 1000
the length of the suffixes array will not exceed 100
all string comparisons are case-sensitive (i.e: Cool != cool)
Efficiency constraints
your function is expected to print the requested result and return in less than 2 seconds
Example
Input   Output
query: "friendly", "outgoing", "powerful", "in"
suffixes: "ing", "ly", "ul", "ful"
friend
outgo
power
in
Explanation
For the word “powerful” we can remove either suffix “ul” or “ful”, but we choose the latter because it’s the longest one.

My code:

```
class MyClass {

       public static void token_stemming(String[] tokens, String[] suffixes) 
  {
        int count=0;
        String[] stemmedList = new String[tokens.length];
        for(int i=0; i<tokens.length; i++)
        {
            int length=0;int flag=0;
            for(int j=0; j<suffixes.length; j++)
            {
               if(tokens[i].contains(suffixes[j]))
               {
                   int strlength = tokens[i].length()-1;
                   int suflegnth = suffixes[j].length()-1;
                   for(int z=suffixes[j].length(); z>0; z--)
                   {
                       if(tokens[i].charAt(strlength--)==suffixes[j].charAt(suflegnth--))
                       {

                       }
                       else
                       {
                           flag=1;
                       }

                   }
                   if(length<suffixes[j].length() && flag==0)
                   {
                        length = suffixes[j].length();
                   }
               }

            }

            stemmedList[count] = tokens[i].substring(0, tokens[i].length()-length);
            System.out.println(stemmedList[count]);
            count++;
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for, but the standard stemmer is by Martin Porter. I have an implementation at my blog: http://programmingpraxis.com/2009/09/08/porter-stemming/.

Comment: There are lots of stemmers. Google "snowball stemmer"

Answer (score 1):

Look for this section of code.

```java
if(tokens[i].charAt(strlength--)==suffixes[j].charAt(suflegnth--))
{
    // this section is where
    // you should code
    // the answer to your homework
}
else
{
    flag=1;
}
```